# Node.js - PostgreSQL - could not determine data type of parameter $1 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg, pg-promise

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL prepared statement using node.js `pg` npm package. However, I keep getting an error:

> could not determine data type of parameter $1

```
 function promiseQuery(sql, values) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        pool.query('select $1 from workers', ['name'], function(err, result) {
            if (err) {console.log(err); reject(err)}
            else resolve(result.rows);   
        })
    });
}
```

In the db the `name` field is set to type `text not null`.

I also tries [pg-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise), but with no success either.

Comment: are you sure you can pass identifier like that?..

Comment: @VaoTsun in the pg documentation there is a very similar example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg

Comment: exactly, the docs specify the syntax: `pool.query('SELECT $1::int AS number', ['2'], function(err, res)` which you aren't using in your code

Comment: in that example, brianc is a text value, not a column name - is it your case?..

Comment: no, I want to create dynamic field list.

Comment: Then pass the `name` as a parameter to your `promiseQuery` and just concatenate it, like: `'select ' + param['name'] + ' from workers'`

Comment: I can do it, but it's very weird to me it's not possible to use prepared statement syntax.

Comment: It wouldn't protect against SQL Injection if you could do dynamic SQL like that.

Comment: I think the whole point of prepared statements is to protect you from being able to do that. with plpgsql you can dinamically build  `execute format('select %I from workers','name')`

Answer (score 4):

In the query `select name from workers`, from the point of view of the [SQL syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html) `name` is an `identifier`, and identifiers can never be passed as `$N` parameters, they must appear verbatim in the command. Otherwise the query cannot be prepared.

`$N` parameters can only appear in the query at positions where literals (constants) would be.

You'd have the same error if trying something similar with the `PREPARE` SQL command, outside of any client-side library:

```
PREPARE p as SELECT $1 FROM pg_class;
ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

The solution is to build the query in javascript with string replacement techniques for column names or table names, before submitting it to the database.

pg-promise does support injection of identifiers into a query with a specific syntax. From [its documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise#sql-names):

```
db.query('SELECT $1:name FROM $2:name', ['*', 'table']);
//=> SELECT * FROM "table"
```

Comment: > string replacement techniques

Doesnt that re open the query to SQL injection?

Comment: @VincentBuscarello: it's safe when adequately quoted. It appears that pg-promise does support the quoting/escaping of identifiers (not sure it did 3 years ago). I've added a bit to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Extending on the answer by Daniel Vérité...

You cannot combine Prepared Statements with dynamic column names, you'd have to generate the query on the client-side.

Using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) syntax for [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names), you can properly escape your query like this:

```
db.any('SELECT $1~ FROM table', [colName])
// OR:
db.any('SELECT $1:name FROM table', [colName])
// OR:
db.any('SELECT ${colName~} FROM table', {colName})
// OR:
db.any('SELECT ${colName:name} FROM table', {colName})
// Etc, other variable syntax, like $[], $//, $<>, $()
```

And if you want to do it for a list of columns, then the simplest way to do it is like this:

```
const colNames = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

db.any('SELECT $1~ FROM table', [colNames])
// etc, the same variations as above, all will generate:
// SELECT "one","two","three" FROM table
```

or from all object properties:

```
const data = {
    one: 123,
    two: true,
    three: 'text'
};
db.any('SELECT $1~ FROM table', [data])
// etc, the same variations as above, all will generate:
// SELECT "one","two","three" FROM table
```

All these methods will properly escape the query, making sure SQL injection is not possible.